# Add status based on Quantity ordered

Tags: oracle, adempiere

I am using Adempiere. I have three tables and a view.
It is `'M_INVENTORY'`, `'M_INVENTORYLINE'`, `'M_REPLENISH'` and the other is `'VW_DAFTARBARANG_AVAILABLE'`.
`M_Inventory` is used when we want to choose `Warehouse`. It shows like this

```
            M_INVENTORY
------------------------------------
M_Inventory_ID  || M_Warehouse_ID
------------------------------------
2000001         || 1000001
2000002     || 1000002
2000003     || 1000003
```

`M_InventoryLine` is used when we want to order stock, in here we put
`Product` and `Quantity` ordered. `M_InventoryLine` is nested from `M_Inventory`, so we order stock from relevant `Warehouse` we chose in `M_Inventory`.

```
                   M_INVENTORYLINE
-----------------------------------------------------------
M_Inventory_ID  || M_Product_ID || QtyInternalUse || Status
2000001         || 1000011      || 5              ||
2000001         || 1000012      || 7              || 
2000001         || 1000013      || 8              ||
```

`M_Replenish` is used to check minimum stock level.

```
        M_REPLENISH
-----------------------------
M_Product_ID || Level_Min
1000011      || 20
1000012      || 15
1000013      || 12
```

The availability of stock can be checked in view `VW_DAFTARBARANG_AVAILABLE`.

```
 VW_DAFTARBARANG_AVAILABLE
--------------------------------------------
M_Warehouse_ID || M_Product_ID || Available
--------------------------------------------
1000001        || 1000011      || 27
1000001        || 1000012      || 20
1000001        || 1000013      || 12 

1000002        || 1000011      || 25
1000002        || 1000012      || 20

1000003        || 1000011      || 25
1000003        || 1000012      || 20
```

I want to put information in `Status` column in table `M_InventoryLine`.

If `Available` is more than minimum stock when stock ordered, then status shows `'Complete'`

Example : `M_Product_ID` = `1000011` (`QtyInternalUse` [order] = `5`, `Level_Min` = `20`, `Av` = `27`, `27-5 = 22` -> Still `above Minimum Level`)

---

If `Available` reaches minimum stock when stock half ordered, then status shows `' Partial'`

Example : `M_Product_ID` = `1000012` (`QtyInternalUse` [order] = `7`, `Level_Min` = `15`, `Av` = `20`, `20-7 = 13` -> Becomes `below Minimum Level`,

Therefore, it can only fulfill 5 out of 7 so the stock still in the minimum level.)

---

If `Available` is in his minimum stock so that stock can't be ordered, then status shows `'N/A`'

Example : `M_Product_ID` = `1000013` (`QtyInternalUse` [order] = `8`, `Level_Min` = `12`, `Av` = `12`, -> Qty `Available` the same as `minimum level`, therefore it can't be ordered)

I've tried making trigger by making something like this =

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER STATUS_MR
BEFORE INSERT ON M_INVENTORYLINE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
WHEN M_INVENTORY.M_WAREHOUSE_ID = M_WAREHOUSE_ID AND M_PRODUCT_ID = M_PRODUCT_ID;

IF :NEW.QTYINTERNALUSE <= VW_DAFTARBARANG_AVAILABLE.AVAILABLE THEN 
:new.Status := "Complete"
ELSIF :NEW.QTYINTERNALUSE > VW_DAFTARBARANG_AVAILABLE.AVAILABLE THEN
:new.Status := "Partial"
ELSE 
:new.status := "Not Available"
END IF;
END;
```

There are still lots of errors and I am confused on how to write the trigger well based on
the condition I have.

Any suggestions will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if trigger is necessary here, maybe view based on this query would be sufficient:

```
select m_inventory_id, m_product_id, qtyinternaluse qty, level_min lvl, available,
       case when available - qtyinternaluse > level_min then 'Complete'
            when available <= level_min then 'Not Available'
            else 'Partial' end status
  from m_inventory i 
  join m_inventoryline il using (m_inventory_id)
  join m_replenish r using (m_product_id)
  join vw_daftarbarang_available d using (m_warehouse_id, m_product_id);
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f216/1)</sup>

If you insist on trigger then below is something what worked for data, logic and examples you provided. 
I added part for updating `qtyinternaluse`, not sure if this is important/possible. Trigger may need adjustments and definitely 
needs tests, anyway I hope this helps. Also - if view `vw_daftarbarang_available` uses table `m_inventoryline` you may encounter
"mutating table error", but this is only my warning as I don't see view definition.

```
create or replace trigger status_mr
before insert or update of qtyinternaluse on m_inventoryline for each row
declare
  v_qty_max number := 0;
begin
  select available-level_min into v_qty_max
    from m_replenish r join vw_daftarbarang_available da using (m_product_id)
    join m_inventory i using (m_warehouse_id)
    where m_product_id = :new.m_product_id and m_inventory_id = :new.m_inventory_id;

  if inserting then
    if :new.qtyinternaluse <= v_qty_max then
      :new.Status := 'Complete';
    elsif v_qty_max <= 0 then 
      :new.status := 'Not Available';
    else
      :new.Status := 'Partial';
    end if;
  elsif updating then
    if :new.qtyinternaluse <= v_qty_max + :old.qtyinternaluse then
      :new.Status := 'Complete';
    elsif v_qty_max + :old.qtyinternaluse <= 0 then 
      :new.status := 'Not Available';
    else
      :new.Status := 'Partial';
    end if;  
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: I was using your query but it says 'ambiguous' column

Comment: So I use this instead

`select 
i.m_inventory_id, IL.m_product_id, IL.qtyinternaluse qty, r.level_min lvl, d.available,
       case when d.available - il.qtyinternaluse > r.level_min then 'Complete'
            when d.available <= r.level_min then 'Not Available'
            else 'Partial' end il.status
  from m_inventory i 
  join m_inventoryline il using (m_inventory_id)
  join m_replenish r using (m_product_id)
  join vw_daftarbarang_available d using (m_warehouse_id, m_product_id);`

but it says FROM keyword not found where expected, why is it?

Comment: Please check: [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f216/2). You cannot use dot in column alias. I modified joins to use `ON` clause instead of `USING`. Both versions work, as you can see in SQLFiddle.